# How to post json with volley to php web service

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

I am trying to Post Json to my restful API with volley but it doesn't work. So far i have tested my web service by sending a json payload through the Advance rest client app on chrome and it returns a json response.... but when i try it with Volley it returns onErrorResponse. Please can someone tell me how to solve this problem, thanks in advance.

Json payLoad:

```
   {"country":"isreal","mobile":"009988778"}
```

Code

```
 private void processLogin() {
    showProgressDialog();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
            Const.LOGIN_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.i("JSON response", "JSON Posting" + response.toString());
            hideProgessDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            VolleyLog.d(ERROR_TAG, "Error: " + volleyError.getMessage());
            hideProgessDialog();
        }
    }){

    @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
        String country_value = country.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String mobile_value = mobile.getText().toString();
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("country",country_value);
        params.put("mobile", mobile_value);
        return params;
    }
    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, login_tag);

}
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the common JSON payload that works through Advanced REST client in Chrome but does not work through Volley.

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing is, you are trying to send a JSON as a part of Headers which won't work.

This is what you need -

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
            Const.LOGIN_URL, **->YOUJSONOBJECTHERE<-**, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.i("JSON response", "JSON Posting" + response.toString());
            hideProgessDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            VolleyLog.d(ERROR_TAG, "Error: " + volleyError.getMessage());
            hideProgessDialog();
        }
    });
```

You need to send `JSONObject` as a part of request not as a part of request headers. Try it out and let me, if it fixes the issue else we troubleshoot it.

And as you already using `JSONObjectRequest`, you niether need to set the content type nor override `getParams()` until or unless you need to send some extra information in your header like AgentType, tokens etc.

Comment: I am glad, it worked. Please consider accepting the Answer so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert object to json string.
2. Override getBody of Volley request
   object
3. Override getBodyContentType to set as json

   ```
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     final String json = gson.toJson(loginDTO);


     GsonRequest<EmailLoginRestResponse> jsObjRequest = new GsonRequest<EmailLoginRestResponse>(
               Request.Method.POST, url,
               EmailLoginRestResponse.class, null,
               this.createLoginRequestSuccessListener(),
               this.createLoginErrorListener()){

           @Override
           public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
               return json.getBytes();
           }

           @Override
           public String getBodyContentType() {
               return "application/json; charset=" + this.getParamsEncoding();
           }
       };

       jsObjRequest.setShouldCache(false);
       this.mRequestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
   ```

GsonRequest.java

https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples/blob/master/src/com/github/volley_examples/toolbox/GsonRequest.java